# Getting an empty response from axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, crud

I have a problem where I keep getting an empty array as the response from my GET operation with axios.
I'm new to REACT and axios alltogether so I believe that I'm doing something wrong here, googling didn't help much.

Here is the code:

```
checkValues =event =>{
    console.log(this.state.username);
    console.log(this.state.password);

    UserDataService.get_username_id(this.state.username).then(Response => {
        this.setState({user: Response.data});
        console.log(Response.data);
    }).catch (e=> {
        console.log(e);
    });

};
```

So basically here at the `console.log(Response.data)` I expect to get a valid response.

I would appriciate your time and any kind of help.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code from the UserDataService

```
import http from "../http-common";

class UserDataService {
  getAll() {
    return http.get("/users");
  }

  get(id) {
    return http.get(`/users/id/{id}`);
  }

  get_username_id(username){
    return http.get('/users/username/{username}');
  }

  create(data) {
    return http.post("/users", data);
  }
}



export default new UserDataService();
```

Here is the code from http-common.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Comment: what you get in the console after `console.log(Response.data)` ?

Comment: empty array, []

Comment: what is the implementation of your `UserDataService.get_username_id`?

Comment: We need more information about the `UserDataService`. Espacially the `get_username_id()` function

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: Great, now we need to see http-common unfortunately. Basically just the source of the axios call

Comment: Can we see your http-common also please

Comment: I checked my backend with postman, it seems to work well there.

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: Can the url actually be ` `/users/username/${username}` `

Comment: @SinanYaman that actually fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: And thank you everybody for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here should be template literal

```
get_username_id(username){
    return http.get(`/users/username/${username}`);
                    ^                           ^
  }
```

rather than

```
get_username_id(username){
    return http.get('/users/username/{username}');
  }

// this will call: "localhost:8080/users/username/{username}" for every input
```